# Unable to call the controller in the angular ui bootstrap $modal

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I want to generate a modal pop up on click of a button. I am using ui bootstrap of angular with $modal service.

Now, when I click on button, I am writing the following code.

```
  $scope.modalOpen = function () {
                    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
                        templateUrl: 'views/includes/someModal.html',
                        controller : //here I want to use the same controller where the current function is getting called
                     });
                };
```

I am unable to call the same controller. Am I making any mistake? I tried Google but no success :( Please suggest. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming the whole reason you want to do this is so you can share data (state) between the modal and the current controller.

You can achieve this without having to share the controller, using the `resolve` field on the modal configuration.

```
function CurrentController($scope, $modal) {
  $scope.list = [];

  $scope.modalOpen = function () {
    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
      templateUrl: 'views/includes/someModal.html',
      controller : 'SomeOtherController',
      resolve: {
        list: function() { return $scope.list; }          
      }
    });
  };
}
```

This means that `list` will be dependency injected into `SomeOtherController`.

```
function SomeOtherController($scope, list) {
  $scope.list = list;
}
```

> `resolve` (Type: `Object`) - Members that will be resolved and passed
>   to the controller as locals; it is equivalent of the `resolve`
>   property in the router.

See the [docs](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal) for `$modal` in angular-ui bootstrap.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am actually calling this open function inside one controller. So, can i reference the same controller name in Controller options of open method. Or is there some other way. I tried that that it didn't work :(

Comment: @Gaurav - My point is that you don't need to do that. You can pass data, and even functions to the modal controller using the resolve option on the modal configuration parameter.

Answer (score 0):

If you open your modal from your controller, you can attempt something like this :

```
var myCtrl = this;
$scope.modalOpen = function () {
      var modalInstance = $modal.open({
           templateUrl: 'views/includes/someModal.html',
           controller : myCtrl 
      });
};
```

But I don't think it's a good practice to reuse a controller instance.

Comment: Sorry, it didn't work :(. It gave me this error : TypeError: Object prototype may only be an Object or null: undefined

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want to make it use the same controller.  Since the scope isn't isolated, your modal can call functions from your current controller.  You can also have an inline controller like the following:

The reason why you couldn't use functions from your current scope is you would have to give the modal your current scope to do that.  Be careful when you do this.  Your modal can mess up your current object.  I went ahead and created a "save" and "cancel" button so that you can undo the changes.

Html

```
<div ng-controller="simpleController">
    {{ item.title }}
    <button ng-click="open();">Click Me</button>
</div>
```

modal template

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="views/includes/someModal.html">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h3 class="modal-title">Title!</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        title: {{ item.title }}<br/>
        Click the buttons below to change the title throught the controller's function
        <button ng-click="fn('test');">test</button>
        <button ng-click="fn('test 1');">test 1</button>
        <button ng-click="fn('test 2');">test 2</button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">

        <button ng-click="close(true);">Save</button>
        <button ng-click="close();">Close</button>
    </div>
</script>
```

javascript

```
angular.module("myApp", ['ui.bootstrap']).controller("simpleController", ["$scope", "$uibModal", function($scope, $uibModal){
    $scope.item = { title: "test", stuff: "other stuff"};
    $scope.fn = function(title){
        $scope.item.title = title;
    };
    $scope.open = function () {
        var intialItem = angular.copy($scope.item);
        var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
            templateUrl: 'views/includes/someModal.html',
            controller:  ["$scope", function(scope){//add other functionality here                  
                scope.close = function(save){
                    if(!save){
                        $scope.item = intialItem;
                    }
                    modalInstance.close();
                }
            }],
            scope: $scope
        }).result.then(function(){
        }, function(){
            $scope.item = intialItem;//modal was dismissed
        });


    };
}]);
```

Comment: Sorry, it did not work. I am unable to pick up the values defined inside the scope function. Could you please edit the answer by showing how can you define and access the scope vales. That will be very helpful.